# BlueZ: What are the meaning of the fields of le_set_advertising_parameters_cp?

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, hci

Is there any specifications document of blueZ which I can refer for development?

I am trying to set advertising type to extended type. So what value I should give.

Please help me to get out of this.

Thanks! In advance.

Comment: Documentation can be found here: https://github.com/bluez/bluez/tree/master/doc , the part you are looking for is: https://github.com/bluez/bluez/blob/master/doc/mgmt-api.txt#L1626

Comment: The bluez documentation contains no details, so see:
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/core-specification/
Vol 4,Part E,Sections 7.8.7 and 7.7.65.2 and 7.8.53 onwards and Vol 3,Part C,Section 11.
Also
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/generic-access-profile/
and
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/company-identifiers/